# How to get the velocity of a rigidBody2d in local space

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can access an object's velocity like so:

```cs
var initialVelocity = rigidBody2D.velocity;
```

However this gives the velocity in world space, rather than local space.
How can i get a `RigidBody2D`'s velocity in local space?

Some background:

I'm trying to create a topdown physics based movement controller. I use the initial velocity together with my setpoint velocity to calculate the acceleration need to accelerate to the setpoint velocity. Then i calculate the force needed and and use `rigidbody2d.AddRelativeForce(...)` to add a force each frame. Therefore i  need the inital velocity in local space.

```cs
                ...
                if (rigidBody2D == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(rigidBody2D)} is null!");

                if (moveComponent.velocitySetPoint.Equals(Vector2.zero))
                    return;

                // Protect ourselves from not setting the max acceleration, causing no objects to move.
                if (moveComponent.maxAcceleration.IsZero())
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(moveComponent.maxAcceleration), moveComponent, $"{nameof(moveComponent)}.{nameof(moveComponent.maxAcceleration)} was {Vector2.zero} so the object won't move, and that is why we throw here. GO: {rigidBody2D.gameObject.name}'");

                // Velocity is speed in a certain direction, e.g. 50 km/h west.
                // See: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/acceleration-velocity-d_1769.html
                // Force = mass * acceleration
                // Acceleration = (finalSpeed - initialSpeed) / time

                var initialVelocity = rigidBody2D.velocity; 
                var finalVelocity = moveComponent.velocitySetPoint;
                var time = deltaTime;
                var mass = rigidBody2D.mass;

                var acceleration = (finalVelocity - initialVelocity) / time;

                Debug.Log(nameof(moveComponent.maxAcceleration) + moveComponent.maxAcceleration);
                Debug.Log(nameof(finalVelocity) + finalVelocity);
                Debug.Log(nameof(acceleration) + acceleration);

                var yClamped = acceleration.y;
                if(yClamped != 0)
                    yClamped = yClamped > 0 ? Mathf.Clamp(yClamped, 0, moveComponent.maxAcceleration.Forward) : Mathf.Clamp(yClamped, -moveComponent.maxAcceleration.Backward, 0);

                var xClamped = acceleration.x;
                if(xClamped != 0)
                    xClamped = xClamped > 0 ? Mathf.Clamp(xClamped, 0, moveComponent.maxAcceleration.Right) : Mathf.Clamp(xClamped, -moveComponent.maxAcceleration.Left, 0);

                var accelerationClamped = new Vector2(
                    xClamped,
                    yClamped
                    );

                var force = mass * accelerationClamped;

                // We've reached acceleration.
                if (force.Equals(Vector2.zero)) // TODO could be changed to veloc and moved upwards.
                    continue;

                Debug.Log(nameof(force) + force);

                rigidBody2D.AddRelativeForce(force);
                ...
```

Any coding related tips are also welcome, especially on how to improve the if statment then clamp part, because i don't find it very readable. I will also need to optimize for performance later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that this is the best way to go but for what you asked you can use [`Transform.InverseTransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html)

> Transforms a direction from world space to local space.
>
> **This operation is unaffected by scale.**

Different to `Transform.InverseTransformVector` this is not affected by your objects scale so it correctly maintains the magnitude of the velocity regardless of any scaling of your object

```
var localVelocity = rigidBody2D.transform.InverseTransformDirection(rigidBody2D.velocity);
```

---

You can however also make your calculations in global space and then instead use

```
rigidBody2D.AddForce(rigidBody2D.transformm.rotation * force);
```

---

Btw this line

```
if (rigidBody2D == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(rigidBody2D)} is null!");
```

is not only quite useless - you will get a `NullReferenceException` anyway if trying to access anything in the case it is `null` - but also a bit dangerous: Unity has a custom implementation for the `==` operator which might skip your check but still not work as expected. You should rather use e.g.

```
if(!rigidBody2D)
{
    Debug.LogError("Aaaaaargh no rigidBody2D!", this);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that out it seems sound. will the warning 'This operation is unaffected by scale.' have any relevant effects?

Comment: @sommmen yes ;) you explicitly **want** your velocity be not affected by scale therefore this method is the one you want, different to `InverseTransformVector` which would alter the magnitude into local space

Comment: "Not that this is the best way to go but for what you asked you can use " any suggestions on how to make that better?  "You can however also make your calculations in global space" yes, although i use AD to turn and WS to thrust forward/backward, so wrapping my head around local space is a bit easier, and also works better with the input i'm getting, so the code becomes easier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the nullcheck! tip - ive tried your answer. for some reason though, even if my rotation is -90 or 90 (so left or right) when I apply my force to addrelative force, i also get a little velocity in the X direction, although no force is applied there, but thats an issue out of scope for this answer, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method based on the answer from derHugo:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extensions for <see cref="Rigidbody2D"/>
    /// </summary>
    internal static class Rigidbody2DExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the velocity in local space.
        /// This is the velocity relative to the local object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">The input <see cref="Rigidbody2D"/></param>
        /// <returns>Velocity in local space</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static Vector2 GetLocalVelocity(this Rigidbody2D input)
            => input.transform.InverseTransformDirection(input.velocity);
    }
```